# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown scrollbar not showing in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-multiselect, vertical-scroll

I have used Bootstrap multiselect plugin in a dynamic table.
Somehow in IE11 the dropdown's vertical scroll bar is missing as the picture below. 
Note: Mouse scroll up/down is working and Its perfectly fine in other browsers

Any clue? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I have realized that there were css classes in the top level div that has affected the color of my scroll bar and up/down arrows, below are those. I had commented them and working fine. One more thing these css classes didn't have effect in Chrome and Firefox so it seemed working fine in those browsers.

Comment: scrollbar-arrow-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-base-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-track-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #f1f1f1;
    scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #f1f1f1;